# Docker error when attempting to build image

Tags: python, linux, docker, terminal, server

I have been trying to setup a container by following the [documentation here](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/)

When I try to run the `docker build -t friendlyhello .` command on the server,  the console spits out an error claiming that:

```
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument(s).
See 'docker build --help'.
```

This, however, doesn't provide me with any information to solve the problem.
When I try to build the `Dockerfile` locally using

```
$ MyMacBook:DockerDirectory docker build -f /Dockerfile .
```

I get the following error:

```
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile
path: lstat .../Documents/DockerDirectory/Dockerfile: no such 
file or directory
```

Does anyone know what might be causing the problem? The `Dockerfile` itself? The code I used? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `$ MyMacBook:DockerDirectory docker build -f /Dockerfile .` expects a Dockerfile in your file system root, not in `/Users/marcbeaujean/Documents/DockerTest`. Try `docker build -f ./Dockerfile .` to use the Dockerfile in your current working directory.

Comment: Did you miss the **.** at the end of docker build command **docker build -t friendlyhello .**?

Comment: @Beginner Their output indicates they do have it. This issue is a matter of ensuring the proper paths to the dockerfile.

Comment: @bluescores this is not the problem but I actually realised an error in my definition of the question which I now fixed for clarification purposes

Comment: Regarding the 2nd error, it is because you've forgotten the `.` in `./Dockerfile`.   It was looking for it in the root of the system

Comment: `docker build .` means "Build the context in the current directory", so you better have a `Dockerfile` in your current working directory. There is no need to specify the `Dockerfile` name unless you are using a non-standard name.

Comment: @Grimmy when I use only `docker build .`, I get the same error that I get from trying to build from the server ( `"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument(s).`). Is this a step in the right direction? What does this error message imply?

Comment: "I get the same error that I get from trying to build from the server". what server? You are doing something we are not aware of here. Are you sure there is a `Dockerfile` in you current path? Run `ls -l` and check.

Comment: Okay so I managed to build the image using the command Grimmy suggested. I also turned my Dockerfile into a .txt file, which might have helped (but I am not sure).